# iterating through an array and performing a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, iteration

I have my original array like this

```
[Array(3), Array(1), Array(3)]
```

each array has this

```
[2, 2, 3]
[1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

I want my final result to be something like this

```
[7,1,6]
```

Comment: This is far from the cleanest example, but you should be able to use `.reduce`: `const result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.push(b.reduce((c,d) => c + d, 0)), [])`. [Docs from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a array `sum` function using `Array.reduce()`, and then map your array, and apply `sum` to each sub-array:

```js
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0)

const arr = [[2, 2, 3], [1], [2, 2, 2]]

const result = arr.map(sum)

console.log(result)
```